# Python + PyQt program freezes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, freeze, cpython

I wrote PyQt application. After it's start I close it (GUI), but timer don't stops and Python sometimes freezes. Only thing to unfreeze it - Ctrl-C, after which following message appears:

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 262, in timerEvent
> > >       KeyboardInterrupt

timer don't stops again, and CPython works very slowly. How to avoid this problem?

EDIT:
I added killTimer() to source but things don't changed that much. CPython is slow and hangs sometimes. How to fully destroy all PyQt objects?

```
Mw = TMainWindow()
TimerId = Mw.startTimer(25)
QApp.exec_()
Mw.killTimer(TimerId)
```

Comment: From the given information, all I can tell you is that there is probably a problem at line 262. Please post more information, like the code at and around that line.

Comment: What do you mean, "timer don't stops" and "python sometimes freezes?"

Comment: That line 262 is not in my source, because message remains the same after adding text above that line. Where is that line I want to know too.
"timer don't stops" - if I print "1" after timer's signal these prints continue to appear after window closing.
"python freezes" - CPython console don't respond to keyboard, sometimes even to Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information this is a complete guess.  One of the more frequent reasons that an application doesn't exit when the GUI is closed is because of [`QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) property being set to false.